# Django multi menu

Tags: шаблоны, django-orm

Всем доброго дня, помогите со структурой

У меня есть две модели

```
   class MenuPages(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'menu'
        verbose_name = 'Меню'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name='Наименование меню',)
    type_menu = models.CharField(max_length=70,choices=MENU_TYPE_CHOISE,verbose_name='Тип Страницы')
    alias = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Casino,blank=True,verbose_name='Прикрепить')


    def __unicode__(self):
        menu = u'Дочернеи меню'
        return format('%s - %s(%d)' % (self.title, menu, ChildMenu.objects.filter(parent_menu=self.pk).count()))
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        symbols = (u"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ",
                   u"abvgdeejzijklmnoprstufhzcss_y_euaABVGDEEJZIJKLMNOPRSTUFHZCSS_Y_EUA")
        tr = dict([(ord(a), ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(*symbols)])
        title = self.title
        title_exists = MenuPages.objects.filter(alias=title.translate(tr)).count()
        if title_exists > 0:
            title = '%s_%s' % (self.title, title_exists)
        self.alias = slugify(title.translate(tr))
        super(MenuPages, self).save(*args, **kwargs)




class ChildMenu(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'child_menu'
        verbose_name= u'Дочернее меню'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Наименование меню')
    type_menu = models.CharField(max_length=70,choices=MENU_TYPE_CHOISE, verbose_name='Тип Страницы')
    alias = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    parent_menu = models.ForeignKey(MenuPages)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Casino,null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        symbols = (u"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ",
                   u"abvgdeejzijklmnoprstufhzcss_y_euaABVGDEEJZIJKLMNOPRSTUFHZCSS_Y_EUA")
        tr = dict([(ord(a), ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(*symbols)])
        title = self.title
        title_exists = MenuPages.objects.filter(alias=title.translate(tr)).count()
        if title_exists > 0:
            title = '%s_%s' % (self.title, title_exists)
        self.alias = slugify(title.translate(tr))
        super(ChildMenu, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Подскажите как организовать древо меню

> Меню1
>   --Подменю1
>   --Подменю1 Меню2 Меню3
>   --Подменю3
>   --Подменю3

Comment: Принципиально клонировать классы для каждого уровня меню? Если в этом нет острой необходимости, то я бы рекомендовал использовать django-mptt или django-treebeard. Тогда все вопросы по организации меню отпадут сами по себе.